# How to get AppEngine User in Production Server through HttpServlet

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

`UserService.getCurrentUser()` returns null in AppEngine HttpServlet post request.

The `resp.sendRedirect()` is also not getting redirected. This is happening in production environment, whereas `user` data is returned in development server.

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
user = userService.getCurrentUser();
if (user == null) {
  resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
  return;
}
```

When `OAuthService.getCurrentUser()` is called `InvalidOAuthParametersException` is thrown.

```
OAuthService oathService = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
try {
  String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
  user = oathService.getCurrentUser(scope);
} catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
  throw new IOException("Error retrieving user info!");
}
```

Getting `User` data in HttpServlet in production environment is throwing error in all possible way. What is the recommended way to retrieve `User` data?

I have shared the `appengine-web.xml` file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>${appengine.app.id}</application>
  <version>${appengine.app.version}</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <env-variables>
    <env-var name="TEST_DATA" value="xxx"/>
  </env-variables>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

`web.xml` is shared below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
  <web-app version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.setv.app.spi.DatabaseApi</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TransactionStatus</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.setv.app.servlet.TransactionStatus</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TransactionStatus</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/transaction/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  </filter-mapping>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you show your appengine.xml configuration file?

Comment: @SimoneTallevi-Diotallevi shared the appengine-web.xml file

Comment: Can I also have a look at your web.xml

Comment: @SimoneTallevi-Diotallevi `web.xml` file is shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to work the UserService need to have a specific web.xml configuration, that force the user to be logged into AppEngine.
In your web.xml is missing the following condition:

```
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

The possible role-name are (admin or *)

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml

Comment: Thanks! It worked in production server. However this is creating a strange issue in development server for which I have created one more question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828507/appengine-multiple-user-credentials-in-development-server