# AppEngine Multiple User Credentials in Development Server

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

When `auth-constraint` is specified in AppEngine Development server `web.xml` file. The `User` injected to endpoint and `User` received from `UserService.getCurrentUser()` in HttpServlet are different.

The user Id for endpoint user is zero and for HttpServlet it is a fixed number. When the `auth-constraint` tag is removed from `web.xml` file, both user ids are zero. But this tag is required for production server.

How to get a single user for development server?

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```